# class variable scope and visiblilty

Tags: php, class, private, public, protected

I have found a code on php.net

```
  class MyClass
{
    public $public = 'Public';
    protected $protected = 'Protected';
    private $private = 'Private';

    function printHello()
    {
        echo $this->public;
        echo $this->protected;
        echo $this->private;
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
echo $obj->public; // Works
echo $obj->protected; // Fatal Error
echo $obj->private; // Fatal Error
$obj->printHello(); // Shows Public, Protected and Private
```

Which is fine for working

But if I use if as:

```
    class MyClass
    {
        public $public = 'Public';
        protected $protected = 'Protected';
        private $private = 'Private';

        function printHello()
        {
            echo $this->public;
            echo $this->protected;
            echo $this->private;
        }
    }

    $obj = new MyClass();
print_r($obj);
```

**It gives me all the information of my class variables.**

So how can I protect my class variable information if I am using it as an API code and class variable holding my database information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the clear explanation for the question on this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22165316/1003917).

If you still wan't to hide it , Make the variable as a `static`

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    public $public = 'Public';
    protected $protected = 'Protected';
    private $private = 'Private';
    static $statvar='This is a secret !'; //<---- A static variable (wont be shown)

}

$obj = new MyClass();
print_r($obj);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
MyClass Object
(
    [public] => Public
    [protected:protected] => Protected
    [private:MyClass:private] => Private
)
```

As you can see `$statvar` is nowhere to be seen.

Answer (score 2):

From https://www.php.net/print_r,

"print_r(), var_dump() and var_export() will also show protected and private properties of objects with PHP 5."

print_r should be used for debugging purpose. You should not use it to expose data using APIs.